# How to delete entry in dynamodb list?

Tags: javascript, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda

I've got a lambda function, which acts as a trigger on a table with best scores of users to handle a leaderboard table.

In my leaderboard table, the sort key is the score, and the player's name is a separate entry with a list, because it's possible that there could be more than one player with the same score. Never mind.

So when adding a player I do:

```
var paramsNewEntry = {
            "TableName": leaderboardTable,
            "Key": {
                "trackId": trackId,
                "time": newValue
            },
            "UpdateExpression": "SET players = list_append(if_not_exists(players, :emptyList), :playersList),
            "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
                ":playersList": [userId],
                ":emptyList":[]
            },
            "ReturnValues": "NONE"
        };
```

And this works fine. I wanted to remove it this way:

```
var paramsOldEntry = {
                    "TableName": myTable,
                    "Key": {
                        "trackId": trackId,
                        "time": oldValue
                    },
                    "UpdateExpression": "DELETE players :playerToRemove",
                    "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
                        ":playerToRemove": [userId]
                    },
                    "ReturnValues": "ALL_NEW"
                }
```

But I get: `Invalid UpdateExpression: Incorrect operand type for operator or function; operator: DELETE, operand type: LIST` error.

The `players` attribute is a list, query response example:

```
{
  "Items": [
    {
      "time": {
        "N": "99994"
      },
      "players": {
        "L": [
          {
            "S": "krystianPostman2"
          }
        ]
      },
      "trackId": {
        "S": "betaTrack001"
      }
    }
  ],
  "Count": 1,
  "ScannedCount": 1,
  "LastEvaluatedKey": {
    "time": {
      "N": "99994"
    },
    "trackId": {
      "S": "betaTrack001"
    }
  }
}
```

I've not seen any question on SO which would provide any details on this in javascript, when using the dynamodb Document API.

Comment: You just need to delete one entry from list if it has multiple values?

Comment: it doesn't matter, just delete the entry specified. It's always a list, if the list has no other values after I have removed the last one, I will detect that in the response data and will remove the entry altogether.

Comment: I would really appreciate a comment when downvoting my question. Why the downvote? Was it inappropriate? Lack of examples/code samples?

Comment: A little outside the question, but using Redis is a good option for leaderboards. It has a type called a [sorted set](https://redis.io/topics/data-types) which is ideal for leaderboards. It makes adding and updating high scores incredibly simple, taking away the logic for this. But, understand if you want to keep your architecture simpler and potentially lower cost.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

DynamoDB API doesn't have an option to delete the value from LIST datatype based on its value. However, if you know the index of the value to be deleted, you can use **REMOVE** to delete the entry from list.

> The DELETE action only supports Set data types.

```
UpdateExpression: 'REMOVE players[0]'
```

If the LIST is going to have only `name` attribute, it is better to save it as SET rather than LIST DynamoDB datatype.

**Creating Set:-**

```
var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
docClient.createSet( ["v1", "v2"]);
```

[Deleting the values from SET using DELETE](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.UpdateExpressions.html#Expressions.UpdateExpressions.REMOVE)

Comment: how about if i change the value to be stored as set? Will then the DELETE work? I'm in the process of rewriting everything to handle it, but if I would know upfront that it will not help, I wouldn't waste my time.

Comment: Yes, you can delete the item from SET. Added the reference link which has some samples as well.

Comment: Yes sir it does. I have changed everything to sets and it's perfect.